# Elasticsearch - Bucket selector aggregation doesn't work - "must be declared inside of another aggregation"

Tags: elasticsearch

I fight with  this problem for few days. I want to filter records by aggregated data (sumA field). This is my request:

```
{
 "size": 10000,
 "aggs": {
 "example_bucket_selector": {
  "bucket_selector": {
    "buckets_path": {
      "sumA": "sum_A"
    },
    "script": "params.sumA > 100"
  }
},
"sum_A": {
  "sum": {
    "field": "A"
  }
},
"sum_B": {
  "sum": {
    "field": "B"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: bucket_selector aggregation [example_bucket_selector] must be declared inside of another aggregation;"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add some sample index data and your expected result

Answer (score 0):

[Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation) is a parent pipeline aggregations that works on the outputs produced from other aggregations rather than from document sets, adding information to the output tree.

**Only sibling pipeline aggregations are allowed at the top level**

In the search query  you are using above, bucket selector aggregation is acting as a top level aggregation, under which you are performing metric aggregation (sum aggregation).

It is very clear from the error message also that bucket selector aggregation, have to be declared inside another aggregation.

> "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: bucket_selector aggregation
> [example_bucket_selector] must be declared inside of another
> aggregation;"

Comment: I've did the same sctructure of request that is in documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Comment: @dante in the Elasticsearch official documentation, they have taken Date histogram aggregation (that is a bucket aggregation), then sum aggregation (that is a metric aggregation) and then they have used Bucket Selector Aggregation that works on the outputs produced by other aggregations.

Comment: @dante As far as I can understand, is your use case something like you are calculating the sum of A field and B fields, and then retrieving those results where SUM_A have a value greater than 100 ? Am I correct ?